# How do I find where powershell is installed on my machine?

Tags: python, powershell, operating-system

I can't figure out where my powershell 7 is installed on my machine.
I'm trying to call os.system('') from within python but it defaults to powershell 5. I tried using 'pwsh' instead of 'powershell' but it just says it doesn't recognize any cmdlets like built in one such as get-host, copy-item.

Comment: `(get-command PowerShell.exe).Path`, `(get-command Pwsh.exe).Path`

Comment: `$env:Path.Split(";")`